# Probability with general solution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let there exist box that a bee is trapped inside of. One of interior walls is black $\{B_1\}$, and the rest are yellow $\{Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5\}$. Let $\{Y_1\}$ be opposite of $\{B_1\}$. If the bee begins a flight from $\{B_1\}$, he is equally as likely to land on $\{B_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5\}$ and never land on $\{Y_1\}$. If the bee leaves from $\{Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5\}$ he is equally as likely to land on any of $\{Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5\}$, but never land on $\{B_1\}$ or the location he took off from.

Questions:
(a) What is the probability the bee is on $\{Y_1\}$ after two flights.
(b) What is the probability the bee is on $\{B_1\}$ after two flights.
(c) What is the probability the bee is on $\{B_1\}$ after $x \geq 2$ flights.

My attempt:
$\textbf{Ways to end on $Y_1$}$
Start on $Y_1$: $(1)*(4)*(1) = 4$ ways
Start on $Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5$: $(4)*(3)*(1) = 12$ ways
Start on $B_1$: $(1)*(4)*(1)= 4$ ways
$20$ different routes to $Y_1$ in 2 flights.

$\textbf{Total possible routes in two flights}$

Start $Y_i$: $(5)*(4)*(4) = 80$ possible routes
Start on $B_1$ and leave $B_1$: $(1)*(4)*(4) = 16$ possible routes
Start on $B_1$ and stay at least once: $(1)*(1)*(5)= 5$ possible routes
$101$ combinations of routes in two flights.

(a)  $\textbf{20/101}$
(b)  $\textbf{1/101}$
(c)  $1/((5)\ast(4)^x+(4)^x+1)$

Comment: That's not an attempt, those are (wrong) answers. An attempt would comprise the steps you took to obtain them.

Comment: I will throw all my notes up there its going to be messy.

Comment: You seem to be implying that there's no middle way between throwing up all your notes and stating only the answers. I don't see why that should be so. The aim should be to state enough of how you got there to make it likely that someone can point out where the mistake is.

Comment: @joriki details added.

Comment: I don't follow all of that, but the main problem appears to be that you assume that all possibilities are equally likely when they aren't. You might want to read up on the [principle of indifference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference).

Comment: @joriki I tried to clean it up even more. My idea was to find all the possible ways to end up on y_1, and then divide it by the total possible routes in two flights. The premise of this thought was we do not know which surface the bee started on. Does this approach not work?

Comment: There is a standard but unpleasant way to tackle such problems. There are $6$ "places" the bee could be where it lands. Call these **states**. The information you have been given provides **transition probabilities**. It can be collected into a matrix $M$. If the current probabilities of being in certain states are collected into a vector $v$, the probabilities for the "next time" are given by $Mv$. So we are interested in $M^kv$. We can use tools from linear algebra to simplify the computation of $M^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your $20$ ways to get to $Y_1$, but not all paths are equally likely.  You can see that because there are $80$ paths starting at $Y_i$, but $21$ starting at $B_1$.  Since there are $5$ times as many $Y_i$ as $B_1$, if all paths were equally probable, there should be $5$ times as many paths starting on $Y_i$.  This is a subtle point.  To arrive on $Y_1$ after two flights you can start on $Y_1$, go elsewhere, and return:  $\frac 16\cdot 1 \cdot \frac14=\frac 1{24}$, you can start on $Y_{non 1}$, go to $Y_{non 1}$, then to $Y_1:  \frac 23 \cdot \frac 34 \cdot \frac 14=\frac 1{8}$or you can start on $B_1$, go to $Y_{non 1}$, then to $Y_1:\frac 16 \cdot \frac 45 \cdot \frac 14=\frac 1{30}$  The total is $\frac 1{24}+\frac 18+\frac {1}{30}=\frac {1}{5}$  A tough problem.

For c, you have to start on $B_1$, probability $\frac 16$ and stay there $x$ times, for a total of $\frac 1{6\cdot 5^x}$

Comment: But you do not know which surface the bee starts on.

Comment: @Joakim:  I misread.  I thought it started on $B_1$

Comment: But there are 5 surfaces in Y_i, why isn't it (5)(4^2)?

Comment: @Joakim:  because you said you don't return to where you started from.  So even the first flight there is one excluded, as I read the problem.

Comment: There are 5 surfaces and the 4^2 is the 2 flights. 4^3 would either suggest there are 4 surfaces with 2 flights or 1 surfaces with 3 flights?

Comment: @Joakim: yes the first $5$ is the surface you start on. But joriki's comment that all routes are not equally probable applies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7978/discussion-between-joakim-and-ross-millikan)

Comment: @Joakim:  I tried to go to chat, but I couldn't figure out how to reply to your last.  I keep missing that the denominator should be $4$ because there are only $4$ places to land if you start at $Y_i$.  I have updated.